# How to only log valid key presses in simple Psychopy experiment

Tags: python, psychopy

I'm new to Python and I'm programming a simple psychology experiment. In a nutshell, I'm presenting participants with a series of randomized images and having them to press one key if they detect a face in a given image.

One of my problems is that the program crashes when participant presses the key too fast - that is, I've noticed that the program logs responses even if the participant is pressing a key when there is no image present. Each image will only be present on the screen for 10 seconds. Participant usually takes ~0.5 second on average to make a response.

Is there a key for me to program the experiment so that that Psychopy will only log key presses ONCE, AFTER image is presented on screen? I've pasted my code below.

Thanks so much.

```
StimList=['Face1.png','Face2.png',]
StimList.extend(['Noise1.png','Noise2.png'])


# randomize lists:
numpy.random.shuffle(StimList)

outstr=""
for TrialNo in range(len(StimList)):

    # load our image:
    img=visual.ImageStim(
        win=win,
        image=StimList[TrialNo],
    )

    # draw the fixation cross and wait for trial start:
    win.flip()
    time.sleep(1) # wait 1 second on fixation cross

    # start a trial: loop until a key has been pressed (or trial times out)
    FaceDetected=0 # same as false
    Responded=0  #revise
    timer=core.Clock()
    timer.reset()
    while (not Responded) and (timer.getTime()<TimeOut): #remove not responded
        img.draw()# outside loop
        win.flip() #outside loop
        keys=event.getKeys(keyList=['y','Y', 'n','N'], modifiers=False, timeStamped=timer)

        if keys:
            if (keys[0][0]=='y') | (keys[0][0]=='Y'):
                FaceDetected=True
                Responded=True
                RT=keys[0][1]
            elif (keys[0][0]=='n') | (keys[0][0]=='N'):
                FaceDetected=False
                Responded=True
                RT=keys[0][1]

    outstr=outstr+str(TrialNo)+", "+ StimList[TrialNo] +", "+str(FaceDetected)+", "+str(RT)+"\n"
    print(outstr)


# first open the file:
outfile=open('tmpdata.csv', 'w')
outfile.write(outstr)
outfile.close()
win.close()
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "the program crashes". If that is truly the case, there should be an error message that you can share, which would help narrow down the issue considerably.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of Python issues with the code above, which I suspect are due to negative transfer from another programming language. For example, in Python you should use `or` in logical comparisons, not `|`, which in Python is the operator for bitwise 'OR', a different beast. Also, you might want to try out the more Pythonic `for TrialNo, stimulus in enumerate(StimList):` in place of `for TrialNo in range(len(StimList)):`, and avoid standard Python functions like `time.sleep()` when you could have more precise control using PsychoPy's timing classes or screen refresh counting.

But in PsychoPy API-specific terms relevant to your main question, you need to call `event.clearEvents()` prior to first drawing your stimulus (e.g. when you reset the trial timer). That will clear the keyboard buffer of any previously-pressed keys.

In further PsychoPy-specific hints, avoid creating objects repeatedly. e.g. the timer only needs to be created once, at the start of the script. Then you just reset it once per trial. At the moment, the reset is actually redundant, as the timer is zeroed when it is created. Timers are simple and multiple creation doesn't really impact performance, but stimuli are more complicated and you should definitely avoid creating them over and over again. e.g. here just create your image stimulus once. Then on each trial, just update its image property. That itself takes time to do, as the file needs to be read from disk. So ideally you would be doing that during the fixation stimulus period, or between trials as it is currently.

Your code really shows a few issues rather than just the one you raised in the question. hence, you might find the forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org more useful than the single question and answer format here at SO.